# How to translate this SQL query into google sheets to count multiple values

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I have a sheet with 3 columns: `player_a`, `player_b`, `result`
Where player_a and player_b are normalised strings representing the different players in the  tournament, and result is either 'W' or 'L'

I would like to create a sheet with the following data:

`player_a`, `player_b`, `num wins`, `num losses`, `winrate` as seen on the screenshot above

In SQL, I would do:

```
SELECT 
  player_a, 
  player_b, 
  num_wins, num_loss, 
  (num_wins*100/(num_wins+num_loss)) as winrate
FROM (
SELECT 
  player_a, 
  player_b, 
  count(case when result = 'W' THEN 1 END) as num_wins, 
  count(case when result = 'L' THEN 1 END) as num_loss
 FROM `scores` 
 GROUP BY player_a, player_b) as grouped_scores;
```

In Google Sheets I tried:

`Query(Sheet1!A3:C, "SELECT A, B, count(case when C = 'W' THEN 1 END), count(case when C = 'L' THEN 1 END)", 0)`

But `case` is not supported in count

So to make this work I ended up doing a first query counting the wins:
`Query(Sheet1!A3:C, "select A, B, count(I) where C = 'W' group by A, B  label count(C) 'num wins'", 1)`

Then, for each created row, I manually created a `num_losses` column and added this formula for each cell below

`=IFNA(query(Sheet1!A3:C, "select count(C) where C = 'L' AND A='"&INDIRECT("A"&row())&"' AND B='"&INDIRECT("B"&row())&"' group by A, B label count(C)''", 0), 0)`

I then also created a column `winrate` where I made formulas for each cell to calculate the winrate

This works but I would like to do all of this in a single formula/query to make it more clean and easier to maintain.

Is there a way to translate my SQL query above into google sheets to do what I described?

Comment: please share a sample sheet.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something alike.

- Columns A, B, C has the raw data
- formula in cell E2:
  `=SORT(UNIQUE(A2:B),1,1)`
- formula in cell G2:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(BYROW(E2:E&F2:F,LAMBDA(efx,if(efx="",,{COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(C:C,(A:A&B:B=efx)*(C:C="W")))),COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(C:C,(A:A&B:B=efx)*(C:C="L")))),(COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(C:C,(A:A&B:B=efx)*(C:C="W"))))*100)/(COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(C:C,(A:A&B:B=efx)*(C:C="W"))))+COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(C:C,(A:A&B:B=efx)*(C:C="L")))))}))))`

-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Given `player A`,`player B`,`result` in A1:Cx of a sheet, the following formula (placed to the side, e.g. in E1) generates the required data in a single formula:

```
=arrayformula(lambda(a,lambda(b,{split(index(b,,1),"|"),filter(b,{0,1,1,1})})(
query(if(a="",0,a),"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col3/(Col2+Col3) label Col2 'Losses', Col3 'Wins', Col3/(Col2+Col3) 'Win rate' format Col3/(Col2+Col3) '0%'")))(
query({A1:A&"|"&B1:B,C1:C,C1:C},"select Col1,count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col3",1)))
```

N.B. 'Losses' precede 'Wins' because the QUERY pivot clause sorts in alphabetical order - it's possible to flip them round but it makes the formula more complex and I'm considering the order to be a cosmetic concern here.

Answer (score 0):

- I use a sheets custom function I wrote to perform my SQL SELECT queries.  I modified it slightly so it would run with my function.

```
=gsSQL("SELECT 
  player_a, 
  player_b, 
  num_wins, num_loss, 
  (num_wins*100/(num_wins+num_loss)) as winrate
FROM (
SELECT 
  player_a, 
  player_b, 
  sum(case when result = 'W' THEN 1 END) as num_wins, 
  sum(case when result = 'L' THEN 1 END) as num_loss
 FROM scores 
 GROUP BY player_a, player_b) as grouped_scores", {{"scores", "F122:H151", 60}})
```

- The second parameter defines the table.  If **scores** is a TAB name on your sheet and the first row contains the field names 'player_a', 'player_b', 'result' - the second parameter is not required.
- My input data:

| player_a | player_b | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Chris | Fred | W |
| Chris | Sam | W |
| Chris | William | L |
| Chris | Simon | W |
| Chris | Mike | W |
| Chris | Alfonso | W |
| Fred | Sam | L |
| Fred | William | W |
| Fred | Simon | W |
| Fred | Chris | W |
| Fred | Mike | L |
| William | Fred | L |
| William | Mike | L |
| William | Alfonso | L |
| Sam | Chris | L |
| Alfonso | Chris | L |
| Sam | Chris | L |
| Chris | Fred | L |
| Chris | Mike | W |
| Chris | Alfonso | W |
| Chris | Fred | L |
| Chris | Fred | L |

- My results:

| player_a | player_b | num_wins | num_loss | winrate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alfonso | Chris | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Chris | Alfonso | 2 | 0 | 100 |
| Chris | Fred | 1 | 3 | 25 |
| Chris | Mike | 2 | 0 | 100 |
| Chris | Sam | 1 | 0 | 100 |
| Chris | Simon | 1 | 0 | 100 |
| Chris | William | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Fred | Chris | 1 | 0 | 100 |
| Fred | Mike | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Fred | Sam | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Fred | Simon | 1 | 0 | 100 |
| Fred | William | 1 | 0 | 100 |
| Sam | Chris | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| William | Alfonso | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| William | Fred | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| William | Mike | 0 | 1 | 0 |

- You need to create a new app script file and copy the custom function into the file.  (it's 5,000 lines, so adding a link only)
  [gsSQL custom function source](https://github.com/demmings/gsSQL/blob/main/dist/gssql.js)
- I have this function entered on my sheet.  See cell A122 on
  [Test Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zmyk7a7u0xvICrxen-c0CdpssrLTkHwYx6XL00Tb1ws/edit?usp=sharing)